# using Google task queues to get contacts from Contacts API

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-contacts-api, task-queue

**Situation**
I am making an function within an already existing website. With this function you can import contacts from Google. Anyway.. My boss told me that I have to use Task-Queues to get the contacts from the api. This is because some people have OVER 9000 (pun intended) contacts and when these people try and import their contacts it will go really slow.

**Question**
How can I use task-queues to get contacts and add these 1 by 1 into an array.

**Code**

```
$return = array();
    if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
        foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
        //retrieve Name and email address
            $exploded = explode("/", $contact['id']['$t']);

            $return[] = array (
                'firstname'=> $contact['gd$name']['gd$givenName']['$t'],
                'lastname'=> $contact['gd$name']['gd$familyName']['$t'],
                'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
                'phoneNumber' => $contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'],
                'city' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$city']['$t'],
                'street' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$street']['$t'],
                'country' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$country']['$t'],
                'birthday' => $contact['gContact$birthday']['when'],
                'id' => end($exploded),
            );
        }
    }
    $google_contacts = $return;
    unset($_SESSION['google_code']);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the use case? A user sends a request to import contacts, the system fetches all contacts from google and saves them to a storage?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to remember about task queues is that they execute independently from the request that called them, so you can't wait for them to finish and return that array to the user - the task needs to store it somewhere or do something with it.

start_import.php:

```
$task = new PushTask('/do_import', $contacts);
$task->add();
echo("Started import job!");
```

do_import.php:

```
if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry'])) {
  foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact) {
    //retrieve Name and email address
    $exploded = explode("/", $contact['id']['$t']);

    $return[] = array (
      'firstname'=> $contact['gd$name']['gd$givenName']['$t'],
      'lastname'=> $contact['gd$name']['gd$familyName']['$t'],
      'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
      'phoneNumber' => $contact['gd$phoneNumber'][0]['$t'],
      'city' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$city']['$t'],
      'street' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$street']['$t'],
      'country' => $contact['gd$structuredPostalAddress'][0]['gd$country']['$t'],
      'birthday' => $contact['gContact$birthday']['when'],
      'id' => end($exploded),
    );
  }
}

// Do something with $return, like persist it to the Datastore or Cloud Storage...
```

app.yaml handlers example:

```
handlers:
- url: /do_import
  script: do_import.php
- url: /start_import
  script: start_import.php
```

And of course, it helps to read the docs for more info:

**Using Push Queues in PHP**
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push